# Can't get xml from php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I've been trying to get data from my database into a table on my website using js/php but I can't get the php to give a valid xml to the script.
This is the php code:

```php
    <?php
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $DBName = "DataBase1";
    
    // Connect to DB
    $connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $DBName);
    if (!$connection)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        //echo "Connected to DB<br>";
    }
    
    // Collect data
    $selectionSD = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `SensorData`");
    $selectionSL = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `SensorLog`");
    
    // Generating XML file
    //$xmlSD = new XMLWriter();
    //$xmlSD->openUri("php://output");
    //$xmlSD->startDocument();
    //$xmlSD->setIndent(true);
    //$xmlSD->startElement("SensorDataTable");
    //while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectionSD))
    //{
    //  $xmlSD->startElement("SensorData");
    //      $xmlSD->startElement("ID");
    //          $xmlSD->writeRaw($row["ID"]);
    //      $xmlSD->endElement();
    //      $xmlSD->startElement("SID");
    //          $xmlSD->writeRaw($row["SID"]);
    //      $xmlSD->endElement();
    //      $xmlSD->startElement("Value");
    //          $xmlSD->writeRaw($row["Value"]);
    //      $xmlSD->endElement();
    //      $xmlSD->startElement("Comment");
    //          $xmlSD->writeRaw($row["Comment"]);
    //      $xmlSD->endElement();
    //      $xmlSD->startElement("DateTime");
    //          $xmlSD->writeRaw($row["DateTime"]);
    //      $xmlSD->endElement();
    //  $xmlSD->endElement();
    //}
    //$xmlSD->endElement();
    //header("Content-type: text/xml");
    //$xmlSD->flush();
    //$xmlSD->endDocument();
    
    // Test code
    $document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $document->formatOutput = true;
    
    $root = $document->createElement('SensorDataTable');
    $root = $document->appendChild($root);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectionSD))
    {
        $node = $document->createElement('SensorData');
        $node = $root->appendChild($node);
    
        // ID
        $dataNode = $document->createElement('ID');
        $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
        $data = $document->createTextNode($row["ID"]);
        $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
        // SID
        $dataNode = $document->createElement('SID');
        $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
        $data = $document->createTextNode($row["SID"]);
        $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
        // Value
        $dataNode = $document->createElement('Value');
        $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
        $data = $document->createTextNode($row["Value"]);
        $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
        // Comment
        $dataNode = $document->createElement('Comment');
        $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
        $data = $document->createTextNode($row["Comment"]);
        $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
        // DateTime
        $dataNode = $document->createElement('DateTime');
        $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
        $data = $document->createTextNode($row["DateTime"]);
        $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
    }
    
    echo $document->saveXML();
    
    // Close DB connection
    $connection->close();
    ?>
```

I've tried to generate the xml a different way but no luck (the commented lines was what I tried first).

To get the xml into a table I use js with this code:

```
console.log(xml);
let i;
const xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
if (xmlDoc === null) {
    console.log("Failed to get response.");
}
let table = "<tr><th>SID</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
const x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SensorData");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td class='center'>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("SID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td class='center'>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";
}
console.log("Changing DB display");
document.getElementById("DB").innerHTML = table;
```

Where xml = the path to the php file.

When trying to run this it gives an error that xmlDoc is null. If I run this using an actual xml file on my drive it works fine.

If I call the php file directly and inspect the source it shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SensorDataTable>
  <SensorData>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SID>1</SID>
    <Value>19.50</Value>
    <Comment>DHT_Temp</Comment>
    <DateTime>2021-10-04 12:57:51</DateTime>
  </SensorData>
  <SensorData>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <SID>2</SID>
    <Value>57.50</Value>
    <Comment>DHT_Humi</Comment>
    <DateTime>2021-10-04 12:57:55</DateTime>
  </SensorData>
  <SensorData>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <SID>1</SID>
    <Value>19.60</Value>
    <Comment>DHT_Temp</Comment>
    <DateTime>2021-10-04 12:58:29</DateTime>
  </SensorData>
  <SensorData>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <SID>2</SID>
    <Value>57.20</Value>
    <Comment>DHT_Humi</Comment>
    <DateTime>2021-10-04 12:58:32</DateTime>
  </SensorData>
</SensorDataTable>
```

How can I fix this issue, I’ve searched the web but the solutions I've come across did not work (creating the xml in a different way for example).

Fixed: change in the php code, added header("Content-type: text/xml"); back:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "***";
$password = "***";
$DBName = "LIDAc";

// Connect to DB
$connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $DBName);
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Collect data
$selectionSD = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `SensorData`");
$selectionSL = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `SensorLog`");

// Generate XML file
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$document->formatOutput = true;

$root = $document->createElement('SensorDataTable');
$root = $document->appendChild($root);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectionSD))
{
    $node = $document->createElement('SensorData');
    $node = $root->appendChild($node);

    // ID
    $dataNode = $document->createElement('ID');
    $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
    $data = $document->createTextNode($row["ID"]);
    $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
    // SID
    $dataNode = $document->createElement('SID');
    $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
    $data = $document->createTextNode($row["SID"]);
    $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
    // Value
    $dataNode = $document->createElement('Value');
    $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
    $data = $document->createTextNode($row["Value"]);
    $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
    // Comment
    $dataNode = $document->createElement('Comment');
    $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
    $data = $document->createTextNode($row["Comment"]);
    $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
    // DateTime
    $dataNode = $document->createElement('DateTime');
    $dataNode = $node->appendChild($dataNode);
    $data = $document->createTextNode($row["DateTime"]);
    $data = $dataNode->appendChild($data);
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo $document->saveXML();

// Close DB connection
$connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: but what is the output?

Comment: When I try to load the page it give me this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementsByTagName')
    at XMLGenerator (script.js:192) (Posted part of the script)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (script.js:111) (Where the script is called)

Comment: but you can echoing the xml in the back to check what hapen with it ...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: You're not sending the output as XML (the header call is commented out). So the browser reads it as HTML and does not build a DOM in the responseXML property. Check the response in the browser devtools.

Comment: Does '$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');' not add the header? I've changed the script form using XMLWriter to using DOMDocument. But you are right on the response, it does not see it as xml but as plain text / html. I'll add the header back, but as far as I know this didn't work either, I'll post something once I've changed it.

Comment: @ThW I did add header("Content-type: text/xml"); back just before echo $document->saveXML(); and you are right, it now is seen as a xml file. I tought the header only was used with the XMLWriter. Thanks!